# populate input hidden with the id of a value from autocomplete.js

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, autocomplete

What i have working at the moment is the autocomplete when i type the name of a person.. what i need is when i select the name automatically fill a hidden field with the id from that person.

my codes:

```
<form action="cadastroAdm.php" method="post" name="clientForm">
      <input type="text" name="clienteId" id="clienteId">   
      <input type="text" name="clienteNome" id="clientes"> 
</form>
```

> jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
// Captura o retorno do retornaCliente.php
    $.getJSON('php/retornar_cliente.php', function(data){
    var dados = [];

    // Armazena na array capturando somente o nome do EC
    $(data).each(function(key, value) {
        dados.push(value.clienteNome);  
        });

        $('#clientes').autocomplete({
        source: dados,
        minLength: 3,   

          select: function(event, ui) {

            $('#clienteId').val(ui.item.id);
            console.log(ui.item.id);                
          },

            });
        });
});
```

> retornar_cliente.php

```
<?php
$hostname = "";
$user = "";
$pass = "";
$basedados = "";
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost; dbname=adv; charset=utf8;",'root','');
$dados = $pdo->prepare("SELECT clienteNome, clienteId FROM cliente ORDER BY clienteNome");
$dados->execute();
echo json_encode($dados->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
?>
```

in the console log i just receive "undefined"..
what i m doing wrong?

Comment: console.log(ui); chk this .

Comment: and than, $('#clienteId').val(ui.clienteId);

Comment: you are only pusing clientName not id to `dados array`, which is the source of the autocomplete.push clienteId to array.it should solve the issue

Comment: how do i concatene it? or push 2 times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

problem solved.. follow the code i used:

> retornar_cliente.php

```
<?php require_once("conexao/conexao.php"); ?>
<?php
$term = trim(strip_tags($_GET['term']));//retrieve the search term that autocomplete sends

$qstring = "SELECT clienteNome as value,clienteId as id FROM cliente WHERE clienteNome LIKE '%".$term."%'";

 $consulta_tr = mysqli_query($conecta, $qstring);
    if(!$consulta_tr) {
        die("erro no banco1");
    }

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($consulta_tr,MYSQL_ASSOC))//loop through the retrieved values
{
        $row['value']=htmlentities(stripslashes($row['value']));
        $row['id']=(int)$row['id'];
        $row_set[] = $row;//build an array
}
echo json_encode($row_set);//format the array into json data
?>
```

> html

```
<form action="cadastroAdm.php" method="post" name="clientForm">
      <input type="text" name="clienteId" id="clienteId">   
      <input type="text" name="clienteNome" id="clientes"> 
</form>
```

> jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        $('#clientes').autocomplete({
        source: 'php/retornar_cliente.php',
        minLength: 3,   

          select: function(event, ui) {

            $('#clienteId').val(ui.item.id);            
                 },
            });     
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Just change your query with this :

```
"SELECT clienteNome, clienteId as id FROM cliente ORDER BY clienteNome"
```

**Or** change your variable in JS with this :

```
ui.item.clienteId
```

**Edit  :**

You didn't push `id` in your `dados` array.

Please refer this link  : http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote

Comment: still "undefined" :(

Comment: What you have changed?

Comment: Also you didn't push `id` in your `dados` array.Please look into this, And refer above link which I've provided to use autocomplete with remote data.

Comment: i m trying to push the id also to array but i dont know how i can transform it in a associative array.. i need to fix my php statement? or can do it in jquery? can you help me?

Comment: That's why i gave a link. Which is simple to use.

Comment: thanks.. it help me a bit.. i found the rest of the answear surfing on websites.. i will post all the code i used